# How to stop Jquery from hiding website toggle menu

Tags: jquery, toggle, togglebutton, hamburger-menu

I am using a toggle-menu which is jquery supported but the issue is the toggle icon disappears on site load and appears after the site has loaded completely. I want to make the icon visible or not disappear even on page load.

```
$ = jQuery;


(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    var n = window.AFTHRAMPES_JS || {};
    n.mobileMenu = {
        init: function () {
            this.toggleMenu(), this.menuMobile()
        },
        toggleMenu: function () {
            e('#masthead').on('click', '.toggle-menu', function (event) {
                var ethis = e('.main-navigation .menu .menu-mobile');
                if (ethis.css('display') == 'block') {
                    ethis.slideUp('300');
                } else {
                    ethis.slideDown('300');
                }
                e('.ham').toggleClass('exit');
            });
            e('#masthead .main-navigation ').on('click', '.menu-mobile a button', function (event) {
                
            });
        },
        menuMobile: function () { if (e('.main-navigation .menu > ul').length) {
                var ethis = e('.main-navigation .menu > ul'),
                    eparent = ethis.closest('.main-navigation'),
                    pointbreak = eparent.data('epointbreak'),
                    window_width = window.innerWidth;
                if (typeof pointbreak == 'undefined') {
                    pointbreak = 991;
                }
            
                

      
       
 e(document).ready(function () {
        n.mobileMenu.init(),
          n.searchReveal();
    }
       ),
        e(window).resize(function () {
            n.mobileMenu.menuMobile(); 
        });

})(jQuery);
```